# Javascript, Sending commands from one page to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to make a sort of "admin panel"  for my website, (e.g. press button on Webpage 1 and then have something happen on all the open instances of Webpage 2, **without refreshing**)

The webpages I want to send from and receive from are on the same server. First thought that came to my head was MQTT, but i'm not sure that it is the right tool for the job.

Trying to do this all in Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Have them all connect with web sockets.

Comment: Never done web sockets before, Are there any useful articles on it?

Comment: There are plenty ;) look into socket.io for starters

Comment: Cannot get this to work, trying out the example code from Mozilla and getting 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed'. Not sure what I am supposed to do. (For context imagine page 1 is "website.org:1000/page1.php" and page 2 is "website.org:1000/page2.php")

Comment: My error is that I cannot set up a server on Page 2, so it has nothing to connect to. How do I do this?